# Hypothesis testing for the binomial distribution - critical region

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution

Consider the following problem:

> $H_0:p=0.2, H_1: p\neq 0.2$
>
> $X\sim B(25,0.2)$
>
> Find the critical region for a hypothesis test using a $5\%$ significance level.

I have found

$$\begin{aligned}
P(X=0)&=0.0038\\
P(X\leq1)&=0.0274\\
P(X\geq9)&=0.0468\\
P(X\geq10)&=0.0173\\
\end{aligned}$$

I therefore said that the critical region is $X=0$ and $X\geq10$, because we require the probability in each tail to be at most $0.025$.

However, the textbook answers say that the critical region is $X\leq1$ and $X\geq10$. They say that $1$ should be selected rather than $0$ because $0.0274$ is closer to $0.025$ than $0.0038$.

Which of these is correct? Or are they both correct?

Comment: To have a 5% test is it absolutely necessary that you have no more than 2.5% in each tail? (What's the significance level of their test? What's yours?)

Comment: @Glen_b The significance level of their test is 4.47% < 5%. But if I accept their answer is correct, I don't understand what the precise definition of the critical region for a two-tailed test should be. For example, if I had $P(X\geq 9)=0.0409$ instead of $0.0468$, then I could pick the critical region to be $X=0$ and $X\geq 9$. Which would I choose then: $X=0$ and $X\geq9$ or $X\leq1$ and $X\geq10$? How would I make this choice?

Comment: Good question! I can think of five different approaches with some claim to be sensible.

Comment: @rbird that would be worth addressing in a question (perhaps as an addition to this one), though it's possible we have covered it.

Comment: (If you prefer nearly equal probability in the tails but *don't* insist that one of them can't slightly exceed 2.5% it should be reasonably clear which choice to make.)

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks, I understand what you mean. This still isn't quite as precise as I'd like it to be, but I get the idea.

Comment: By "it's possible we have covered it" I meant "in answers elsewhere on site" (i.e. you might find more information with a site search). Failing that my suggestion would be to add this to your question.

Comment: Exact binomial: If $X \sim BINOM(25,.2),$ Then $P(X \le 1) = .0274 [`sum(dbinom(0:1, 25, .2))` returns 0.02738973] and $P(X \ge 10) = .0173$ [`sum(dbinom(10:25, 25, .2))` returns 0.01733187] so the total rejection probability is below 5%. Including 9 in the critical region puts the probability over 5%. // Approx normal: $E(X) = \mu = np = 5,\, SD(X) = \sigma = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 2.$ Elem texts often 'sweep discreteness under the rug' by saying not to reject if $\mu -1.96\sigma \le X \le  \mu +1.96\sigma,$ which means not to reject for $X$ between 1.08 and 8.92. Question becomes how to round.